# Trying to convert a sequence of int to delimited string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have been using a DelimitedStringHelper extension to convert a sequence of items to a delimited string with `IEnumerable<T>`. By default, ToString() is called on each item in the sequence to formulate the result using a default delimiter of ', '.

This had the effect of taking:

```
public enum Days
{
    [Display(Name = "Monday")]
    Monday,
    //Left out other days for brevity
    [Display(Name = "Saturday")]
    Saturday
}
```

and, combined with the rest of the model:

```
[Mandatory(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one day")]
[Display(Name = "What are the best days to contact you (select one or more days)?")]
[ContactClientDaySelector(BulkSelectionThreshold = 6)]
public List<string> ContactClientDayCheckBox { get; set; }
```

along with code for `[ContactClientDaySelector]:

```
public class ContactClientDaySelectorAttribute : SelectorAttribute
{
    public override IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
    {
        return Selector.GetItemsFromEnum<ContactClientDay>();
    }
}
```

would display a checkbox list with "Monday, ..., Saturday", by calling in the view thusly:

```
@Html.FullFieldEditor(m => m.QuotePartRecord.ContactClientDayCheckBox)
```

*Note: `FullFieldEditor` is a special helper that iterates through the `enum` and using the `BulkSelectionThreshold` would pick either a radiobutton list, dropdown list, checkbox list or multi-select list -- in this case "6" would trigger the creation of a checkbox list because my `enum` had a collection of 6 items (i.e., days).*

My controller only checks validity of model state and passes on to the confirmation view:

```
public ActionResult WrapUp(string backButton, string nextButton)
{
    if (backButton != null)
        return RedirectToAction("ExpenseInformation");
    else if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    else
        return View(quoteData);
}
public ActionResult Confirm(string backButton, string nextButton)
{
    if (backButton != null)
        return RedirectToAction("WrapUp");
    else if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var quoteConfirm = _quoteService.CreateQuote(quoteData.QuotePartRecord);
        return RedirectToAction("Submitted");
    }
    else
        return View(quoteData);
    }
```

Now, for posting the checkboxes selected by the user, I used the following in a confirmation view page:

```
[ContactClientDaySelector]
[ReadOnly(true)]
public List<string> ContactClientDayCheckBoxPost
{
    get { return ContactClientDayCheckBox; }
}
```

This, combined with the DelimitedStringHelper would display the selections. For example, if Monday and Tuesday were both selected by the user, the Post would display "Monday, Tuesday".

However, I had to change my code around a bit and, and use `int` instead specifically for checkboxes (long story short: using NHibernate generates a cast error because of the use of `List<string>`, and this was a way around that problem).

I had to remove the `enum` and replaced it with this class:

```
public class ContactClientDay
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I modified my Selector class thusly:

```
public class ContactClientDaySelectorAttribute : SelectorAttribute
{
    public ContactClientDaySelectorAttribute()
    {
        //For checkboxes, number must equal amount of items
        BulkSelectionThreshold = 6;
    }
    public override IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
    {
        var contactClientDay = new List<ContactClientDay> 
        { 
            new ContactClientDay {Id = 1, Name = "Monday"},
            //Left out other days for brevity
            new ContactClientDay {Id = 6, Name = "Saturday"},

        };
        return contactClientDay.ToSelectList(m => m.Id, m => m.Name);
    }
}
```

I changed my model to this:

```
public virtual int? ContactClientDayCheckBox { get; set; }
```

I changed my Post to this:

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public string ContactClientDayCheckBoxPost
{
    get { return QuotePartRecord.ContactClientDayCheckBox.ToString(); }
}
```

If I do `public int? ContactClientDayCheckBoxPost` instead, nothing would be displayed on the confirmation page.

If I instead used `public string ContactClientDayCheckBoxPost` and then did `ContactClientDayCheckBox.ToString()`, it would only display the "Name" of the first value selected ("Monday" only, not "Monday, Tuesday").

I cannot figure out how to programatically convert a sequence of `int` in this scenario (possibly with an extension)?  Any thoughts/examples? Thanks in advance.

For reference, here is the extension for `DelimitedStringHelper` I am using:

```
public static class DelimitedStringHelper
{
    public static string DefaultDelimiter = ", ";

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a sequence of items to a delimited string. By default, ToString() will be called on each item in the sequence to formulate the result. The default delimiter of ', ' will be used
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.ToDelimitedString(x => x.ToString(), DefaultDelimiter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a sequence of items to a delimited string. By default, ToString() will be called on each item in the sequence to formulate the result
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="delimiter">The delimiter to separate each item with</param>
    public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string delimiter)
    {
        return source.ToDelimitedString(x => x.ToString(), delimiter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a sequence of items to a delimited string. The default delimiter of ', ' will be used
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selector">A lambda expression to select a string property of <typeparamref name="T"/></param>
    public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, string> selector)
    {
        return source.ToDelimitedString(selector, DefaultDelimiter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a sequence of items to a delimited string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selector">A lambda expression to select a string property of <typeparamref name="T"/></param>
    /// <param name="delimiter">The delimiter to separate each item with</param>
    public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, string> selector, string delimiter)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return string.Empty;

        if (selector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selector", "Must provide a valid property selector");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(delimiter))
            delimiter = DefaultDelimiter;

        return string.Join(delimiter, source.Select(selector).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: I really have hard time understanding what's being asked here. Could you provide a short and yet complete example allowing to easily reproduce the problem? Narrowed down versions of your Model, Controller and View should suffice.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Overhauled the code and text to give a better understanding. Thanks.